# HighChart : plot line and plot click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot, highcharts

I am using highchart for some drilldown functions.

In my case I am having a area chart with an onclick event.

I'd like to let the user click on an area plot to add a line and change the chart color. I therefore have two functions: one changing the chart color and one adding a plot line where the user has clicked.

Below is the plot line click event:

```
chart: {
        type: 'area',
        events: {
        click: function(evt) {
            var xValue = evt.xAxis[0].value;
            var xAxis = evt.xAxis[0].axis;
            $.each(xAxis.plotLinesAndBands,function(){
                if(this.id===myPlotLineId)
                    {
                        this.destroy();
                        }
                });
                xAxis.addPlotLine({
                    value: xValue,
                    width: 1,
                    color: 'red',
                    //dashStyle: 'dash',                   
                    id: myPlotLineId
                    });
                    }
                }               
            },
```

And this is the color update event, which is inside the `plotOptions`

```
  plotOptions: {
            series: {
            point: {
            events: {
                click: function(event) {
                    //selector
                    if(previousPoint){
                        previousPoint.update({ color: '#FFC7C3' });
                        }
                        this.update({ color: '#fe5800' });

                        //drilldown trigger
                         var date = this.category.replace(/\-/g,'')
                         $("#datepicker").click();
                        //put somewhere else not in the custom
                         $("#drilldowndate").html(parseInt(date));

                         $(window).scrollTop(1700);

                         window.setTimeout(function(){
                            $("#trendDrill").click();
                            },500); 

                        window.setTimeout(function(){
                            $("#periodChecker").text($(".ifNoDrill").data("target"));
                            },1000);
                        }               
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

And I'd like the `addplotline` function and the update plot color function both working on the same click, so when the user clicks on the desired area, the chart changes the specific color and a plot line appears.

**JS fiddle Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/Xm4vW/70/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change add plotLines in your point click event. I have made two functions, one responsible for changing colour of your point (also on hover) and one for adding plotLines:

```
 var updatePoint = function(point) {
      if (previousPoint) {
        previousPoint.update({
          color: '#7cb5ec',
          marker: {
            states: {
              hover: {
                fillColor: '#7cb5ec',
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
      previousPoint = point;
      point.update({
        color: '#fe5800',
        marker: {
          states: {
            hover: {
              fillColor: '#fe5800',
            }
          }
        }
      });
    },
    addPlotLine = function(evt) {
      var point = evt.point;
      var xValue = point.x;
      var xAxis = point.series.xAxis;

      Highcharts.each(xAxis.plotLinesAndBands, function(p) {
        if (p.id === myPlotLineId) {
          p.destroy();
        }
      });
      xAxis.addPlotLine({
        value: xValue,
        width: 1,
        color: 'red',
        id: myPlotLineId
      });
    };
```

You can use this functions inside your click event function:

```
point: {
  events: {
    click: function(event) {
      updatePoint(this);
      addPlotLine(event);
    }
  }
}
```

Here you can find an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/Xm4vW/72/

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted to achieve. One extra question, how can i destroy all of the plot line after i update my series?

Comment: You can again loop over your plotLines and remove them using .remove(): http://jsfiddle.net/Xm4vW/74/

Comment: Sorry one last question, what if i have few different charts? I found out that the function won't clear the plotline on the other chart when i click on different chart, please see update

Comment: Please go to this link to check out the questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564418/highchart-plot-line-click-event-for-multiple-chart